# trigger for Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

Can anyone tell me trigger which sends the email on change of opportunity stage. to opportunity contact with email template

```
trigger emailtemplate on Opportunity(after update)

{
          List<Opportunity> oList = Trigger.new;
          List<Opportunity> nList = trigger.old;
        if(oList[0].StageName !=nList[0].StageName)
          { 
           //code to send email template

          Set<Id> OpportunityIds= new Set<Id>(); 
          Map<id,Contact> ConMap = new Map<id,Contact>([select id,LastName,FirstName from Contact where Id in :OpportunityIds]);

        //  String[] toAddresses = new String[] {.email__c}; 
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

         //   mail.setTargetObjectId(Opportunity.ContactId);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
           mail.setUseSignature(false);
           mail.setBccSender(false);
             mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

         if (Trigger.isUpdate) { 
         if(Opportunity.Stage == 'Prospecting') {
          EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'pros'];
          mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
          Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   
      } 
        if(Opportunity.Stage == 'Qualification') 
        {
          EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'pros'];
          mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
          Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   
      }   
   }

}

}
```

Comment: U mean whenever u change stage one of many templates should be send as email

Comment: @Sunny Yes email template should be send to contact belongs to that opportunity.

Comment: So u need to write trigger on opportunity, in the trigger check trigger.old.stage != trigger.new.stage.... and pick one template....This is the process.where did u get stuck

Comment: @Sunny Can you give me the sample trigger for above requriment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Code,it is working for me,use this

```
trigger emailtemplate on Opportunity(after update)
{ 

List<Opportunity> oList = Trigger.old;
 List<Opportunity> nList = trigger.new;

  if(oList[0].StageName !=nList[0].StageName) { //code to send email template

      Set<Id> OpportunityIds= new Set<Id>(); 
     Map<id,Contact> ConMap = new Map<id,Contact>([select id,LastName,FirstName,email from Contact where Id in :OpportunityIds]);

     List<Contact>  sList = [select id,LastName,FirstName,email from Contact where Account.Id =:nList[0].accountid limit 1];

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
       mail.setUseSignature(false);
       mail.setBccSender(false);
         mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);


      EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate limit 1];
      mail.setTemplateId(et.id);

      mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {sList[0].email}); 
    mail.setTargetObjectId(sList[0].id); 
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

      Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   


}

}
```

Comment: i created like this and i getting error may i know where should i have to change code

Comment: Sunny i tried u r code but it is not working .may i know what i have to do.I think we have to change at email template query.

Comment: no error but it is not working i have to change any line from your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12836/discussion-between-sathya-and-sunny)

Comment: i tried again but it not working. can you send me the updated code to my mail.

Comment: from above code which template we are sending.

Comment: i have to do any changes in  your code while working with your code.

Comment: No just copy it that enough

Comment: i need some small information as per our trigger we are sending same template our each stage, i want to send differnt templates for different stages.i have to chage any query.

Comment: Yes when "EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate limit 1];" this query u need to pick the template id as per ur criteria...

Comment: i need to send different templates for different opp stages for this how to change the query.

Comment: Query with template name like [Select id from EmailTemplate where name='some idetifier' limit 1]

Answer (score 1):

For me it sounds like job for workflows....
Thanks to use workflows your job will be easier and you don't have to care about code coverage

Comment: May i know how to write a trigger..can you suggest me.

Comment: Best way to learn is read SF documentation http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_triggers.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_triggers.htm|SkinName=webhelp , I can help you if you will tell me what are requiments for this trigger?

Comment: i created a workflow but it is not working may i know what i have to do.in "Recipient Type" what i have to select to send a mail to particular contact which belongs to that opportunity

Comment: You have to configure it right. try to read about this.
If you will read manual and will still have problems then I will try to help you :)

Comment: i configure i select created and evert time it's updated and slect template i am struck how to select the contact who belongs to that particular opportunity. for that contact i have to send a email

Comment: You have to have relation beetwen opportunity and some contact(lookup) and then you have to fill in New Email Alert field called Recipient Type as Related Contact and chose your contact field

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12834/discussion-between-sathya-and-birthus)